# How can I access and process nested arrays on JSON to import on Excel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, exceljs

Here is the JSON data :-

```
"data": [
    {
      "character_id": "5785304882",
      "id": 289222,
      "login_status": {
        "created": "2022-09-21T19:52:04.394",
        "status": "Started Competition"
      },
      "name": "user_01",
      "team": "DA ATRAX ESPORTS"
    }
```

Here is the JS Code :-

```
gacworksheet.columns = [
  { header: "User Name", key: "name", width: 10 },
  { header: "Team Name", key: "team", width: 10 },
  { header: "Character ID", key: "character_id", width: 10 },
  { header: "Login Time", key: "loginTime", width: 10 },
  { header: "Login Status", key: "loginStatus", width: 10 },
];

var json = JSON.parse(result);
var userData = json['data']; 
userData.forEach(user => {
  for (var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
    var loginTime = userData[i].login_status.created;
    var loginStatus = userData[i].login_status.status;
  }
   gacworksheet.addRow(user);
});
let gacdata = gacworksheet.getSheetValues();
gacMData = gacdata.map(function(r){
  return [r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5]];
});
console.log(gacMData);
```

When I `console.log` the data, the data which is inside the array is `undefined`. How to set the array value to a Key?

Result of console.log(gacMData);

```
[
    'User Name',
    'Team Name',
    'Character ID',
    'Login Time',
    'Login Status'
  ],
  [ 'user_01', 'DA ATRAX ESPORTS', '5785304882', undefined, undefined ],
  [ 'user_02', 'DA ATRAX ESPORTS', '5670142641', undefined, undefined ],
```

Comment: What do you get, when you log `gacdata`?

Comment: [
    'User Name',
    'Team Name',
    'Character ID',
    'Login Time',
    'Login Status'
  ],
  [ 'user_01', 'DA ATRAX ESPORTS', '5785304882', undefined, undefined ],

Comment: So, you get an array of arrays?

Comment: In place of undefined I want to get ```login_status.created``` and ```login_status.status```

Comment: Please explain the userData.forEach code block as it makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Yogi there is multiple data in Json file and I'm using ```userData.forEach``` to add the data in worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userData.forEach(user => {
    let newUser = {...user}
    newUser.loginTime = user.login_status.created;
    newUser.loginStatus = user.login_status.status
    gacworksheet.addRow(newUser);
  });
```

Comment: Yes the data comes when you ```console.log``` inside the ```userData.forEach```, But i want that data in ```gacMData``` instead of undefined.

Comment: Could you please share `addRow` Function (gacworksheet.addRow(user)) and `getSheetValues` function (gacworksheet.getSheetValues()) ?
So that i can run the code and my end and check the issue.

Comment: it is the function of exceljs

   ```const gacworkbook = new excelJS.Workbook();```
    ```const gacworksheet = gacworkbook.addWorksheet("GAC Data");```

Comment: I have edit my answer. Just replace the forEach loop with this code. With this i am able to console the expected values in `gacMData`. I hope this will help.

Comment: If it helped you, please accept my answer as correct and give rating to it. Thank you.